# Multiple variables in one column?

Tags: php, mysql

is it possible to have multiple variables in one column for when someone does a checkbox search? Let's say the checkboxes are like this:

Music to dance to:
1.Oldies
2.Reggae
3.pop
4.house

And let's say there's a table by the name of 'Events', and one of the columns is music.
Can the column somehow contain let's say, 1,3,4 which would be searched for if someone selects checkboxes 1,3 or 4 it would return this row?

Thanks :)

Comment: This could work, but is a bad idea: you should normalize these data. Make an extra table musicForEvent which has one EventID and one Music column, now add three rows if an event has three musics.

Comment: Normalization is not the solution here. What you want is something more expressive than a relational model, so I might as well suggest using NoSQL.

Comment: @Frits busting out NoSQL, noice!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you describe is a many-to-many relationship. This means there can be many events, and each event can have several styles of music covered. On the other hand, a style of music can be represented on many events.

Generally, you can express these kinds of relationships with a helper table and two different tables for 'Event' and 'Music': Assume 'Event' has a primary key id and so does 'Music', but there is no column in either 'Music' or 'Event' referencing each other. Instead, to set up a link between them, you would create a third table 'Event_Music' with columns 'event_id' and 'music_id'. Consider this example:

```
Table Event

id | name
 1 | Event A
 2 | Event B
 3 | Event C


Table Music

id | style
 1 | oldies
 2 | reggae
 3 | pop
 4 | house


Table Event_Music

event_id  |  music_id
   1      |      1
   1      |      3
   3      |      4
```

This tells you that there is going to be Event A with oldies and pop and there is going to be Event C with only house music.

Comment: Great, this was easy to understand, however when I return tables - will there be multiple rows for each event because of this?

Comment: Yes, if an event features more than one music style, then there's more than one row in Event_Music. Let's say your user checked 1 and 3, for an event that features "oldies" and "pop". Then to get the corresponding events, you would query for entries in Event_Music that have the same event_id, and there is both an entry with this event_id that has music_id=1 and one with music_id=3.

Comment: Hmmm, that doesn't seem ideal as I would like only one row returned - what about a column for each music style?

Comment: Works if your music styles are a fixed-size set. If you're absolutely sure you will never have more styles than 4, it's okay to use. But otherwise the 'helper table' approach is obviously friendlier if you need to extend.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for the MySQL [`SET`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/set.html) column type

Comment: +1 as an alternative if you didn't wish to follow the traditional, many-to-many approach of relational databases.

Comment: This sounds like the best alternative really, since I don't want multiple rows returned for the same event.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, no, you can't have multiple values in the same field (at least in a sane way).

You would do this in a separate table lets call it something like [events_genres] and it would have a [foreign key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key) on your [Events] table primary key and another foreign key on the [genres] table primary key.

For example :

```
[events_genres]
events_id    genre_id
1            1
1            2
1            3
2            3
```

The `events_id` is the id of the event in table [Events] and `genre_id` is the id of the genre (Oldies, Reggae, php...) in the [genres] table.

Comment: Technically you should have a bridge/join table (e.g. `events_to_genres`) in this setup. The `genres` table should only contain the base genre records.

Comment: @Jason McCreary Yeah I think you cought me while I was editing my post :) I think it's clearer now.

Comment: Doesn't this solution return more then one row for each event?

Comment: @pufAmuf Yes because an event can have none, one or many genres attached to it.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to look into the many:many database structure.  Do some research, set up some tables, and give it a shot.  It's one of the basic forms of databases.

Answer (score 1):

Put music type into a separate table, and create a column and a Foreign Key that points from Events to the music type table. Then you store the PK of the music table into the Events table.